# Push_back into map<int,vector<char>>*

Tags: c++

c++

map<int, vector>* maxcounts;

When I have a pointer to map maxcount how do I write this next statement correctly?

maxcounts[-m.second]->push_back(m.first);

without referencing a pointer I write

maxcounts[-m.second].push_back(m.first);

```
map<int, vector<char>> maxcounts;
for (pair<char, int> m : counts) {
    if (maxcounts.count(-m.second))
        maxcounts[-m.second].push_back(m.first);
    else
       maxcounts.insert({ -m.second, {m.first} });
}
```

Comment: Hint:  You don't need an `if` statement to do this.  It can be done in a single line of code.  Check out the return value of the `insert` call.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out how to use a pointer to the map, first rewrite your loop this way:

```
std::map<char, int> counts;
//...
std::map<int, std::vector<char>> maxcounts;
for (std::pair<char, int> m : counts) 
    maxcounts.insert({-m.second, std::vector<char>()}).first->second.push_back(m.first);
```

Note that the return value for [std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is a `std::pair`, where the `first` of the pair is an iterator to the existing item if the item already is in the map, or the iterator to the newly inserted item.  Thus you can perform the test and insert in one line without need for an `if` statement.

The `push_back` will occur, regardless of whether the item inserted in the map is new or if the item existed.  Note that for a new entry, the `std::vector` being inserted starts as empty.

Given this, the pointer to the map version is very simple:

```
std::map<char, int> counts;
//...
map<int, vector<char>>* maxcounts;
//
for (pair<char, int> m : counts) 
    maxcounts->insert({-m.second, std::vector<char>()}).first->second.push_back(m.first);
```

Now, why you need a pointer to a map in the first place is another issue, but to answer your question, the above should work.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. The `std::vector<char>` has a default constructor. So why not just do `(*maxcounts)[-m.second]` to get a reference to the vector? That would get rid of all of the `.first` and `->second` nonsense.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Better to use `operator []` to be less terse, or if more information is needed on the insertion and using `C++ 17`, then `insert_or_assign`.

Answer (score 0):

I would likely write something like:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>>* maxcounts = ...;
for (std::pair<char, int> m : counts)
  (*maxcounts)[-m.second].push_back(m.first);
```